# How I can put variable in ansible j2 template correctly

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have problem with ansible j2 template when i run this task 
    I use this task for create grafana datasource

```
- name: Get certifacete 
  slurp:
    src: /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server/certmanager/CMCA/ca-db/newcerts/00.pem
  register: cert

- name: test
  uri:
    url: https://127.0.0.1:3000/api/datasources
    method: POST
    validate_certs: no
    force_basic_auth: yes
    user: "{{ grafana_admin_user }}"
    password: "{{ grafana_admin_password }}"
    body: "{{ lookup('template', 'test_template.j2') }}"
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
```

template

```
  {
    "name": "Cloudera Manager",
    "type": "foursquare-clouderamanager-datasource",
    "url":"https://{{ hostvars[groups['tag_Group_cm'][0]]['ec2_private_ip_address'] }}:7183",
    "access":"proxy",
    "isDefault":false,
    "basicauth":true,
    "basicAuthUser":"{{ managerUser }}",
    "basicAuthPassword":"{{ managerPassword }}",
    "jsonData": {
    "cmAPIVersion":"{{ cmapi }}",
    "tlsAuthWithCACert": true},
    "secureJsonData":{
        "tlsCACert": "{{ cert['content'] | b64decode | string }}"
    },
    "database": "foursquare-clouderamanager-datasource"}
```

I got this error when I use this template with variable

```
   fatal: [10.0.1.31]: FAILED! => {"cache_control": "no-cache", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "[{\"classification\":\"DeserializationError\",\"message\":\"invalid character '\\\\\\\\' looking for beginning of object key string\"},{\"fieldNames\":[\"Name\"],\"classification\":\"RequiredError\",\"message\":\"Required\"},{\"fieldNames\":[\"Type\"],\"classification\":\"RequiredError\",\"message\":\"Required\"},{\"fieldNames\":[\"Access\"],\"classification\":\"RequiredError\",\"message\":\"Required\"}]", "content_length": "359", "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Thu, 14 Nov 2019 10:48:45 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "expires": "-1", "json": [{"classification": "DeserializationError", "message": "invalid character '\\\n' looking for beginning of object key string"}, {"classification": "RequiredError", "fieldNames": ["Name"], "message": "Required"}, {"classification": "RequiredError", "fieldNames": ["Type"], "message": "Required"}, {"classification": "RequiredError", "fieldNames": ["Access"], "message": "Required"}], "msg": "Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request", "pragma": "no-cache", "redirected": false, "status": 400, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=86400; preload", "url": "https://127.0.0.1:3000/api/datasources", "x_frame_options": "deny", "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block"}
```

When i use template without variable works fine 
example debug output without variable:

```
"body": {
                "access": "proxy",
                "basicAuthPassword": "passs",
                "basicAuthUser": "user",
                "basicauth": true,
                "database": "foursquare-clouderamanager-datasource",
                "isDefault": false,
                "jsonData": {
                    "cmAPIVersion": "v4-5",
                    "tlsAuthWithCACert": true
                },
                "name": "Cloudera Manager",
                "secureJsonData": {
                    "tlsCACert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nV7jPmgHqYTNRw/zvfdOP1qeqhkIeTp8vPbp3lw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                },
                "type": "foursquare-clouderamanager-datasource",
                "url": "https://127.0.0.1:7183"
            }
```

Example debug output with variable:

```
"body": "{\n\"name\": \"Cloudera Manager\",\n\"type\": \"foursquare-clouderamanager-datasource\",\n\"url\":\"https://127.0.0.1:7183\",\n\"access\":\"proxy\",\n\"isDefault\":false,\n\"basicauth\":true,\n\"basicAuthUser\":\"user\",\n\"basicAuthPassword\":\"pass\",\n\"jsonData\": {\n\"cmAPIVersion\":\"v4-5\",\n\"tlsAuthWithCACert\": true},\n\"secureJsonData\":{\n    \"tlsCACert\": \"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nV7jPmgHqYTNRw/zvfdOP1qeqhkIeTp8vPbp3lw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n\"\n},\n\"database\": \"foursquare-clouderamanager-datasource\"}"
```

I think maybe I have problem in this string  **`"tlsCACert": "{{ cert['content'] | b64decode | string }}"`**   but i don`t have any idea how to solve this problem

Comment: Could you add more details than "I think I may have a problem here", as you don't say anywhere what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I have problem here "tlsCACert": "{{ cert['content'] | b64decode | string }}" becouse when I put certifacate  from debug message in jinja template task has been fineshed without any error but when I run this thask with  variable in jinja template I got error

Comment: The problem is that if he use directly the certificate in his http request, he has no error. when he is using a template and slurping previously the certificate and use it to feed the template he has an error 400 on his http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using **string templating** to compose a structured document (in this case JSON); jinja2 does not know it is JSON, only that it is text. You would receive a similar error if you were to try and template `{"hello": "{{ world | string }}"` using a variable of `world="abc\ndef"` because the `\n` in the string is literally inserted in the mustaches, but JSON does not allow newlines in string literals.

You have two paths forward: either ensure the rendering is JSON safe with `| to_json` instead of `| string`, or compose the `body` as an actual `dict` so that `uri:` will serialize it correctly

I suspected that is what was happening, but I confirmed it the same way you can: echo that `{"body":  "{\n\"name\": \"Cloudera Mana...` string through `jq -r .body` (or `python -c "import sys, json;print(json.load(sys.stdin)['body'])"` if you don't have `jq` handy) and you will see that `tlsCACert` has newlines in it